# Material Angular 14 - Global Variables not working

Tags: sass, angular-material, css-variables

rRecently upgraded to Material Angular 14 and Material Angular CSS Vars v3.

We have a lot of customization of the angular material components so we use the native scss files and leverage them.  In our variables file (variables.scss) we have a bunch of SASS variables for our material elements.
**_variables.scss**

`$mat-option-hover-background: mat-color($primary,400);`

Then in the options theme files we call that variable.
**material/core/option/_option-theme.scss**

```
.mat-option {
    color: mat-color($foreground, text);
    &:hover:not(.mat-option-disabled),
    &:focus:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
      background: $mat-option-hover-background;
    }
```

I'm unable to get this to work. I'm simply trying to set the variables in my variables file using the material-css-vars-functioncs.

I have tried add material-css-vars/src/lib/_variables.scss with @use in my variables file so the colors will compile. But then I get the error that I am trying to call @use "@angular/material" as mat; in two places.

I'm not sure how to get this to work. If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Tried moving the variables file in different places, tried calling a mixin. I don't know if I'm trying to implement this in a way that no longer works.